# Stream response to downstream clients in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a controller proxy api endpoint where it receives different request payloads which are intended to different services. This controller validates payload and adds few headers based on certain rules. In this current context, i do not want to parse the received response from upstream services. proxy method should simply stream response to downstream clients so that it can scale well without going into any memory issues when dealing with large response payloads.

I have implemented method like this:

```
suspend fun proxyRequest(
        url: String,
        request: ServerHttpRequest,
        customHeaders: HttpHeaders = HttpHeaders.EMPTY,
    ): ResponseEntity<String>? {
        val modifiedReqHeaders = getHeadersWithoutOrigin(request, customHeaders)

        val uri = URI.create(url)
        val webClient = proxyClient.method(request.method!!)
            .uri(uri)
            .body(request.body)
        modifiedReqHeaders.forEach {
            val list = it.value.iterator().asSequence().toList()
            val ar: Array<String> = list.toTypedArray()

            @Suppress("SpreadOperator")
            webClient.header(it.key, *ar)
        }

        return webClient.exchangeToMono { res ->
            res.bodyToMono(String::class.java).map { b -> ResponseEntity.status(res.statusCode()).body(b) }
        }.awaitFirstOrNull()
    }
```

But this doesn't seems to be streaming. When i try to download large file, it is complaining failed to hold large data buffer.
Can someone help me in writing reactive streamed approach?

This is what i have done finally.

```
suspend fun proxyRequest(
        url: String,
        request: ServerHttpRequest,
        response: ServerHttpResponse,
        customHeaders: HttpHeaders = HttpHeaders.EMPTY,
    ): Void? {
        val modifiedReqHeaders = getHeadersWithoutOrigin(request, customHeaders)

        val uri = URI.create(url)
        val webClient = proxyClient.method(request.method!!)
            .uri(uri)
            .body(request.body)
        modifiedReqHeaders.forEach {
            val list = it.value.iterator().asSequence().toList()
            val ar: Array<String> = list.toTypedArray()

            @Suppress("SpreadOperator")
            webClient.header(it.key, *ar)
        }

        val respEntity = webClient
            .retrieve()
            .toEntityFlux<DataBuffer>()
            .awaitSingle()
        response.apply {
            headers.putAll(respEntity.headers)
            statusCode = respEntity.statusCode
        }
        return response.writeWith(respEntity.body ?: Flux.empty()).awaitFirstOrNull()
    }
```

Let me know if this is truly sending data downstream and flushing?

Comment: well if you stick the body into a string `bodyToMono(String::class.java)` then the computer needs to know the size of your string and allocate n size in memory. And to do so it needs the entire file. I dont know kotlin, etc, but you need to stream the body probably into a `Flux<DataBuffer>` that then can stream this along to the calling client.

Comment: i tried that but not sure if i did correctly. can you share psudo code in ur comfortable language

Comment: No, sorry, i dont have time, then someone else needs to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code snippet fails with memory issues because it is buffering in memory the whole response body as a `String` and forwards it after. If the response is quite large, you might fill the entire available memory.

The second approach also fails because instead of returning the entire `Flux<DataBuffer>` (so the entire response as buffers), you're only returning the first one. This fails because the response is incomplete.

Even if you manage to fix this particular issue, there are many other things to pay attention to:

- it seems you're not returning the original response headers, effectively changing the response content type
- you should not forward all the incoming response headers, as some of them are really up to the server (like transfer encoding)
- what happens with security-related request/response headers?
- how are you handling tracing and metrics?

You could take a look at the [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) project, which handles a lot of those subtleties and let you manipulate requests/responses.

Comment: we are returning response headers to downstream services.  also we are thinking of adding filters to remove sensitive headers.

can you please explain which modules of spring cloud gateway helps and in what aspect?

Comment: The whole thing. It can be embedded.

Comment: thanks for guidance. i will study spring cloud to understand better fit